# preg_match with multiline doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, line-breaks, multiline

I have the following code :

```
$data = "numbers{One
Two
Three}";

preg_match("~(?<=numbers{)(.*?)(?=})~", $data, $result);
echo $result[0];
```

The preg_match doesn't work i don't know why
if the data is just one line then it works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `.` doesn't match a newline use the `s` modifier:

```
~(?<=numbers{)(.*?)(?=})~s
```

Or you could just match on NOT `}`:

```
~(?<=numbers{)([^}]*)(?=})~
```

Not knowing all of you requirements, you may be able to simplify it:

```
preg_match("~numbers{([^}]*)}~", $data, $result);
echo $result[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

all regex engines suport many search modificators, like for caseInsensitive serch or multiLineSourse, try "m" modificator

```
preg_match("~(?<=numbers{)(.*?)(?=})~ms", $data, $result);
```